# Material ui only insert theme in html head but doesn't other styles (server side rendering)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I've used this tutorial (https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/  ) to configure my SSR but it doesn't work correctly, or it should work in this way? When server returns Html page it consists of only material UI theme but doesn't have styles which I've created in my components, material UI doesn't inject these styles in the head , and you see the broken page on first loading, it looks strange.

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets()

const components = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
  <StaticRouter location={ctx.request.url} context={routeContext}>
    <Provider store={ctx.store}>
      <IntlProvider>
        {sheets.collect(
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Application history={history} />
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        )}
      </IntlProvider>
    </Provider>
  </StaticRouter>
)
```

Here is a snippet from my code, I do it the same way as in the tutorial. And one more thing, here as I see styles in head on client-side loading (all styles inserted correctly)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understood that it isn't possible to solve it, material load styles in this time and only what you can do to prevent it , you can use https://material-ui.com/components/skeleton/, to show the user some content before styles will be loaded to the page. As I understood even youtube do the same approach.